# undefined reference to `printb'

Tags: c, undefined, extern

In my header `interface.h` I have a function,

`extern void printb(char *, unsigned short, char *);`

Which is called in `main.c` as follows,

`printb(" available", EXTRACT_16BITS(ptr), LLDP_CAP_BITS);`

And I have included the the heder file in my `main.c` as follows.

`#include "interface.h"`

However, when I try to compile, I get the error stating the following,

`undefined reference to 'printb' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I tried to do some research on this and came up empty handed. any  help to solve this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Thank you :)

Comment: where printb is implemented?

Comment: Well, uh, have you linked against the library or compiled with the object where printb is defined?

Comment: you didn't link correctly. Probably you need to type this commande line `gcc -o myprog main.c interface.c`.

Comment: Thank yu very much for your replies guys :) I will reply soon :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly,You need to find out where the definition of function printb() is. If it is in some other static library ,then you need to link to that lib while compiling. For example, if your printb function is in printb library, then compile your source as below.

   gcc -o prog main.c -l printb
2. If your printb function is in another standalone printb.c file, then compile your code as

   gcc -o prog main.c printb.c

   Either of these should work for you.